# how to add jquery cycle plugin effect in an application

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on jquery cycle.My slider is now working properly .
It should hide all images (only display one image ) .And there will be dots below the image user click dots and it will goes to that selected dot image.
Here is fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/KJHUp/

```
$('#s3').cycle({ 
    fx:    'fade', 
    speed:  2500 
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to 
**HTML** :

```
 <ul id="nav"></ul>
```

**JS:**

```
$('.pics').cycle({ 
fx:    'fade', 
speed:  200 ,
slides: '> img',
pager:   '#nav',
pagerAnchorBuilder: pagerFactory
```

});

```
function pagerFactory(idx, slide) {
    var s = idx > 2 ? ' style="display:none"' : '';
    console.log(idx);
    return '<li'+s+'><a href="#">'+(idx+1)+'</a></li>';
};
```

Check [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hardiksondagar/KJHUp/3/)

NOTE : I have put 1,2,3 number instead of dots, you can change that to dot and also styling of ul

Comment: There is no dot below the images

Comment: Like In this example there should be three dots